# Convert yyyy_mm_ddThh-mm-ss to date object?

Tags: java, date, datetime, time, datetime-format

Is it possible or are there any method which is automatically convert this type of string to the date object ?

String is = `yyyy_mm_ddThh-mm-ss`

I need the convert this string to date object because i have to compare with real time. The substring or split may work but i just want to learn is there any special thing or not

**EDIT :** 
From cause of `T` in the middle of, simpleDateFormat not working correctly from my side.

**SOLVED :**
I forget to put `'` before and after the T

```
SimpleDateFormat("yyyy_mm_dd'T'hh-mm-ss");
```

Comment: use simpledateformat.you don't dare to spend time on internet do you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to skip `T` with single quotation `'T'`. Also note that, small `'m'` is the format of minute. Use capital `'M'` for month format. Try,

```
   DateFormat df=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy_MM_dd'T'hh-mm-ss");
   System.out.println(df.format(new Date()));
```

For details, read this documentation of [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse the String with the date format like this:

```
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy_MM_dd'T'hh-mm-ss");
    Date date;
    try {
        date = sdf.parse(sdf1.format(dateX) + " " + time);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

### Joda-Time

[Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) provides built-in formatters for a variety of such ISO 8601 formats. So you need not even bother with creating that format string.

See this class:

http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/ISODateTimeFormat.html

### Update

I learned you don't even need the formatter with Joda-Time 2.3.

Your string is almost in ISO 8601 format. Replace those underscores with hyphens.

The constructor of DateTime accepts a string in [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format.

```java
// © 2013 Basil Bourque. This source code may be used freely forever by anyone taking full responsibility for doing so.
// import org.joda.time.*;
// import org.joda.time.format.*;

DateTime dateTime = new DateTime( "2001-02-03T04:05:06", DateTimeZone.UTC );
System.out.println( "dateTime: " + dateTime.toString() );
```

When run…

```
dateTime: 2001-02-03T04:05:06.000Z
```

### Time Zones

By the way, your question fails to address the issue of time zones. My example code assumes you meant UTC/GMT (no time zone offset). If you meant otherwise, you should say so. Date-time work should always be explicit about time zones rather than rely on defaults.